# how will effect in total, if qty will increase or decrease?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want if i increase the qty then total should also effect and when decrease the quantity,from the total also should subtract.on increase and decrease qty amount working perfect but there is a issue in total,How can i do this,Please help if someone have idea?

```
     holder.inc.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener(){// this method is for increase the quantity by the cart_id
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {

                            float amount=0,Amt_with_cgst_sgst=0,qty_return=0;;
                            float gst= Float.parseFloat( holder.txt_gst.getText().toString() );
                            bill_id= Integer.parseInt( holder.txt_bill_id.getText().toString() );
                            Cat_id= Integer.parseInt( holder.txt_cart_id.getText().toString() );
                            float qty= Float.parseFloat( holder.txt_per_qty.getText().toString());
                            float price = Float.parseFloat( holder.txt_price.getText().toString() );
                            float inc_qty= Float.parseFloat( holder.inc_quantity.getText().toString());
                            float CGST=  Float.parseFloat(holder.txt_cgst.getText().toString());
                            float SGST= Float.parseFloat( holder.txt_sgst.getText().toString());
                           if(inc_qty<billlist.get(i).getC_qunanity()){ //it will increase the value  till that value  exit before the change only
                                inc_qty++;
                                holder.inc_quantity.setText(String.valueOf(inc_qty));
                             }
                            float sales_qty= billlist.get( i).getC_qunanity();
                            qty_return = sales_qty+inc_qty;
                            amount =(price/qty)*inc_qty;
                            float sales_amt= billlist.get(i).getC_Amount();
                            float amt_return = sales_amt+amount;
                            Float cgst_sgst =amount*(CGST+SGST)/100;
                            Amt_with_cgst_sgst= amount+cgst_sgst;
                            holder.txt_amount.setText(String.valueOf(Amt_with_cgst_sgst));

                            Add_Sales.txt_grand_total.setText( String.valueOf(getTotal_Add( Amt_with_cgst_sgst )));//getTotal is a method for calculating the total

                            holder.desc.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {//this method is for decrease the quantity by the cart_id
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view){
                                float gst= Float.parseFloat( holder.txt_gst.getText().toString() );

                            bill_id = Integer.parseInt( holder.txt_bill_id.getText().toString() );
                            Cat_id = Integer.parseInt( holder.txt_cart_id.getText().toString() );

                            float qty = Float.parseFloat( holder.txt_per_qty.getText().toString());
                            float price = Float.parseFloat( holder.txt_price.getText().toString() );
                          //  float Amt= Float.parseFloat( holder.txt_amount.getText().toString());
                            float inc_qty= Float.parseFloat( holder.inc_quantity.getText().toString());
                            float CGST =  Float.parseFloat(holder.txt_cgst.getText().toString());
                            float SGST = Float.parseFloat( holder.txt_sgst.getText().toString());
                            float qty_return=0;
                            if(inc_qty>0){
                                inc_qty--;
                                holder.inc_quantity.setText(String.valueOf(inc_qty));
                                float sales_qty= billlist.get(i).getC_qunanity();
                                qty_return  = sales_qty-inc_qty;
                              }
                            float amount =(price/qty)*inc_qty;//calculating the amount by price or qty without gst
                            float sales_amt = billlist.get(i).getC_Amount();
                            float amt_return = sales_amt-amount;
                            Float cgst_sgst = amount*(CGST+SGST)/100;
```

//calculating amount with gst                              float Amt_with_cgst_sgst= amount+cgst_sgst;
                                    holder.txt_amount.setText(String.valueOf(Amt_with_cgst_sgst));//setting the amount after doing calculation

```
                           Add_Sales.txt_grand_total.setText( String.valueOf(getTotal_Sub(Amt_with_cgst_sgst )));

    public float getTotal_Add(float price){ //calculating the total amount here
            for(int i=0;i<billlist.size();i++){
                price+=billlist.get( i ).getC_Amount();//getting the amount by the position wise
            }
            return price;
        }
```

Comment: Simply you need to do calculation and update data on increase and decrease button click. You can simply check do it

Comment: @Piyush it's happend in database case but don't want by updating database

Comment: Then alter your database without affecting it

Comment: i don't know how,please help me

Comment: Do you want to add new column to database? If not then you don't need to alter table.. Also share your code

Comment: @Piyush yes, after increase or decrease qty,data will be update and insert when click on buttuon

Comment: Where is it insert? In db? Then do have total amount column in db?

Comment: yes i have total amount column in db

Comment: @rachna You should make one function which calculate total price based on quantity. That function will be called while increment and decrement quantity.

Comment: i made but it's not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201372/discussion-between-piyush-and-rachna).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use mutable live data for the quantity and billing amount you have to take 2 mutable live data variable , and observe quntity live data when  you change value it reflect in obesrver and than do process on update value and again push the value in price data

var qua=Mutablelivedata()
var price=MutableLivedate()

qua.observe(ths(@lifecyle may be activity or fragment),Observe{
    //here you can get updated qua value

```
 price.value=value after opration
```

})

use data two data binding so reflect

Answer (score 0):

when ever user click`-` or `+` icons call this method

```
private void updateProductPrice(int quantity){
    itemPrice=(quantity*itemCostPrice);
    tv_Price.setText("$"+itemPrice);
}
```

Comment: @rachna you mean the total price of the cart or ?

Comment: for me I store cart data into `local database(sqlite)` then when I update item quantity I also update cart table then total will be update

Comment: but i don't want to this actually it's not in case of cart, in case of cart i am doing the same but it's when item return from the customer side then customer will return then qty will be decrease from the exiting qty that time,user will click on add return and then cart is updating